# What is the best way to fix this triple-nested ternary operator?

Tags: javascript, nested, conditional-operator

I have a code snippet that sorts an array of objects. Each of the objects looks something like:

```
{
      "id": "60ff9eb7c793c6197dae5d42",
      "matches": 1,
      "timestamp": "2021-07-27T05:46:52.469Z",
      "likes": 23
}
```

I have a triple nested ternary expression that sorts them first by matches, then by likes, then by the timestamp. The code is below.

```
        bestMatches.sort((a, b) =>
          a.matches < b.matches
            ? 1
            : a.matches === b.matches
            ? a.likes < b.likes
              ? 1
              : a.likes === b.likes
              ? a.timestamp.getTime() < b.timestamp.getTime()
                ? 1
                : -1
              : -1
            : -1
        );
```

What is the best way to convert this to "good" code? I had a lot of difficulty using if/elses in this case, and I know that nesting ternary expressions is bad practice. As always, if you take the time to answer or attempt to answer this question, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subtract to get the difference between the `matches`, then the `likes`, then the times.

```
bestMatches.sort((a, b) => (
  (b.matches - a.matches) ||
  (b.likes - a.likes) ||
  (b.timestamp.getTime() - a.timestamp.getTime())
));
```